# Batch convert .cdr into .svg with script

Tags: svg, coreldraw

I need to create a script, in any language, for Windows, that can take .cdr files as input and convert them into .svg files. I've searched extensively for information but still don't have a solution. Thanks for any help.

For now i have python script that work on `pylibcdr`:

```py
from pylibcdr import CDRParser


filename = "test-1"

parser = CDRParser(filename + ".cdr")
print(parser.xml)

f = open(filename + ".svg", "w")
f.write(parser.xml)
f.close()
```

But when im trying to open output .svg files in CorelDRAW it have some artifacts

Comment: Proprietary formats like .cdr usually have a lot of "subformats" introduced over the time by newer version.  I highly recommend to first try a batch conversion approach using this proprietary environment – e.g by installing a recent trial/demo of corel draw and search for  macros, apllication scripts.  Standalone parsers may only support a subset of all features used in the cdr object model. Besides, graphic applications quite often have features that can't be translated to SVG – e.g mesh gradients.  multiple artboards/pages. I guess the best you can get is ~90% working svg export.

Comment: You might also check the free inkscape application which also has at least some cdr support and a quite powerful commandline interface.

Comment: Please could you describe the artifacts in details at the original issue trackers (may be uploading the source images, if possible):

- if you believe they originate from Python layer: https://github.com/mpds-io/pylibcdr/issues/new
- if you believe they concern the libcdr core: https://gerrit.libreoffice.org/q/libcdr

Many thanks ahead.